# Why does it appear that some lineno internal commands are never called?

Tags: macros, line-numbering

At the end of [`lineno`'s cryptic documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.pdf), the author lists certain "for wizards commands."

I'm trying to implement a special tag for the first line number, so I thought I would probably begin by redefining `\makeLineNumberLeft`. For some reason, this has no effect. The same is true for quite a few `lineno` internals.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \def\makeLineNumberLeft{}
    \def\theLineNumber{}
    \modulolinenumbers[5]
    \runninglinenumbers*

    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

How do I manipulate `lineno`'s number-printing mechanism?

**Edit:**

To be specific, I want to print `Line` above each instance of the line number 5 (presumably using negative `hspace` and `graphicx`'s `raisebox`). Also, `lineref` references have to be accurate, so I can't hack the numbering at a low level.

Comment: `\theLineNumber`? If you want to print the counter value it is `\thelinenumber`. But I don't understand what you want to achieve. What is your **tag** here? A label for future reference? A specially printed line number?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: "if the current line number is 5, print `Line` in a raised box with negative hspace."

Comment: `\makeLineNumberLeft` is an internal macro, pushing the numbers to the left margin. `\def\makeLineNumberLeft{}` redefines it to do nothing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, which macro prints the line number?

Comment: @AndrewCashner: `\runninglinenumbers*` does this too

Comment: Small side note: You've asked some questions during the last days, some of them got good answers, you should consider accepting them. Please consider also to provide clearer questions, because it's sometimes completely unclear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is the right thing the O.P. wants to have ...

Requesting `running numbers`, the macro `\makeLineNumberRunning` is used for typesetting the numbers. The query about the specific line number, say, 5, is easy with `\ifnum\value{linenumber} = 5` and using a `\raisebox` then.

The value of the linenumber, the raising and the displayed text can be changed, see the relevant macros.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\raiseboxoffset}
\setlength{\raiseboxoffset}{0.5\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\linenumberwhereitshouldappear}{5}
\newcommand{\mylinetext}{\bfseries\textcolor{red}{Line~}}

\runninglinenumbers*

% Copied from lineno.sty and slightly edited. 
\def\makeLineNumberRunning{% 
  \hss\linenumberfont
  \ifnum\value{linenumber} = \linenumberwhereitshouldappear %
  \raisebox{\raiseboxoffset}{\mylinetext}%
  \fi
  \LineNumber\hskip\linenumbersep%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent See the important line \ref{mysuperline} please!!!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, \linelabel{mysuperline} ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.
\end{document}
```

Referencing works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Is it considered bad practice to redefine a command with the `\the` prefix?

Comment: @SimonKuang: Yes, I would say so. `\the....` commands are always counter output macros, and `\the\baselineskip` etc. would give you the literal length of some length register, as would `\the\token` for a token. Don't use `\the...` for macro names

Comment: I want to have accurate `\lineref`, though.

Comment: @SimonKuang: See my comment below your question, about the `clarity` of your questions

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @SimonKuang it isn't clear what your edit changes, doesn't this answer the question (before or after the edit)?

Comment: @SimonKuang: See the update please